# Non-hydrate forming salts?

Tags: aqueous-solution

Are there any water-soluble salts that don't form hydrates?

Hydration seems very thermodynamically favorable, as evidenced by its abundance. It also makes sense since the solvation and hydration thermodynamics are related. I can't find any evidence of non-hydrate-forming salts by brute force search or keyword googling. Anyone know of any?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesium_chloride

Comment: Sodium Chloride.

Comment: AlaskaRon Surprisingly, NaCl does indeed form a hydrate: http://www.phasediagram.dk/binary/sodium_chloride.htm